# Переменные сбрасываются при запуске в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я запускаю игру в редакторе Text(text) сбрасывается и там появляется None(text)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class Settings : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Text sensitivity;
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            sensitivity = GetComponent<Text>();
            sensitivity.text = Convert.ToString(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Sensitivity"));
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            
        }

        public void SensorUpdate(float value)
        {
            Debug.Log(value);
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Sensitivity", value);
            sensitivity.text = Mathf.RoundToInt(value * 100) + "%";
        }

        public void OnMenuButtonClick()
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Либо не сохранены изменения (сцена, префабы и пр.). Либо проблема в классе Settings. Либо действительно пропадает компонент Text. В любом случае проблема с Вашей стороны.

Comment: Сцену сохранил, не помогает. Приложил код класса Settings. Причём Debug.Log(value) работает.

Comment: Надо полагать, что уже при старте в логе ошибка "Null reference exception"? Действительно ли на этом же GameObject, где Settings, располагается компонент Text (причем размещен там в самом начале, а не после Settings.Start())?

Comment: ...И хорошей практикой является использовать атрибут [RequireComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html), если где-нибудь в инициализации присутствует GetComponent(). В Вашем случае - [RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас глупая ситуация, либо компонент `Text` находится на том же объекте, что и `Settings` и тогда код выглядит так:

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
// RequireComponent исключает ошибки, обязывая наличие
// подобно тому, как Text не существует без CanvasRenderer
[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]

public class Settings : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text _text;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        _text = GetComponent<Text>();
    }
}
```

Либо `Text` и `Settings` находятся на разных объектах и поле с ссылкой на компонент `Text` задаётся в инспекторе. Ни какого `GetComponent` в этом случае нету.

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class Settings : MonoBehaviour
{
    // SerializeField отображает поле в инспекторе несмотря на приватность
    // а поле наверняка внутренней кухни, не должно быть публичным
    [SerializeField] private Text _text;

    // свойство на случай, если другим нужна ссылка, но без прав изменить эту ссылку
    public Text Text { get => _text; }
}
```

Одновременно устанавливать и в инспекторе и запрашивать через `GetComponent` одно и тоже бессмысленно.

П.С.

`Convert.ToString(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Sensitivity"));` можно писать проще: `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Sensitivity").ToString()`. `ToString()` есть у всего, хоть `123.ToString()` или `(1+2.3f).ToString()`.

`Mathf.RoundToInt(value*100)` не имеет смысла потому, что `float*int=int`(`value*100`) или `float/int` или `float+int`, он и так это округлит, но всегда в меньшую сторону как `FloorToInt`, а не `RoundToInt`. Нужно `value*100f`, что бы указать вещественное число `float`. Либо приведением типов `value*(float)100`.